# Web.config transform moving namespace declaration

Tags: c#, xml, web-config, nlog

Using [this online tester](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/) it is easy to see the following issue

I have a web.config that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <nlog/>
</configuration>
```

And a transform that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <xdt:Import assembly="AppHarbor.TransformTester" namespace="AppHarbor.TransformTester.Transforms"/>

  <nlog xdt:Transform="Replace"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <targets async="true">
      <target name="LogMill" xsi:type="FallbackGroup" returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">
        <target xsi:type="LogMillMessageBus"/>
        <target xsi:type="File" fileName="..\LogMill-FailSafe.log" layout="${TextErrorLayout}"/>
      </target>
    </targets>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

But the output is not what I expect, it moves the xsi namespace declaration down to the element that uses it, which causes nlog to fail to parse the configuration with the error `Parameter p4 not supported on FallbackGroupTarget`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <nlog>
    <targets async="true">
      <target name="LogMill" p4:type="FallbackGroup" returnToFirstOnSuccess="true" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <target p4:type="LogMillMessageBus" /><target p4:type="File" fileName="..\LogMill-FailSafe.log" layout="${TextErrorLayout}" />
      </target>
    </targets>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Is there a transform option or syntax that I can apply to prevent it from moving the namespace declaration? I couldn't find anything in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It looks like simply removing the xmlns:xsi completly and just having type="..." instead of xsi:type="..." in the transform file works, but it would be nice to keep the declaration to improve the editing in visual studio experience.

Comment: It is a workaround (or maybe the solution? I'm not sure) but if you repaat the namespace in your source config `<nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>` and using `<nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xdt:Transform="Merge">` in your transformation then it works.

Comment: I had the exact same issue with web.config transforms and nlog. I avoided the issue by removing the namespace in the transformation rule, as the namespace is only really needed for intellisense when working in Visual Studio. It's not necessary in a release environment. I realise that this is over a year old but thought my comment might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration to the topmost element and it should be OK

Answer (score 1):

In my case instead of

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

I had to use

```
xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"
```